# Statustext: undefined with status:200 using Axios to pass textinput values using react native XAMPP server

Tags: php, api, react-native, axios

Error message: 
I don't seem to understand the warning.

```
"<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/rest_api_myblog/api/post/create.php</b> on line <b>8</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined property: stdClass::$title in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/rest_api_myblog/api/post/create.php</b> on line <b>25</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined property: stdClass::$author in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/rest_api_myblog/api/post/create.php</b> on line <b>27</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined property: stdClass::$category_id in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/rest_api_myblog/api/post/create.php</b> on line <b>28</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/rest_api_myblog/models/Post.php</b> on line <b>99</b><br />
{"message":"Post Created"}"
```

Axios

```
 onCreate = event => {
        event.preventDefault();  
        let cat_id = (this.state.cat + 1);
        const body = {
           'author' :this.state.author,
          'title': this.state.title,
          'body' : this.state.body,
          'category_id':String(cat_id)
        };
        console.log(body);
        axios.post(`http://localhost/rest_api_myblog/api/post/create.php`,{
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
         }, 
        body})
        .then(res => {console.log(res)
        })
        .catch(e => console.log(e));
      }
```

There was no single error when I post using POSTMAN but immediately I try from the front-end. I receive "Post created" with the warnings above and no post created except the date and ID (autoIncrement)

**PHP:This is my create function**

```
public function create(){
    //create query
    $query ='INSERT INTO '. $this->table .' SET title = :title,body = :body, author = :author, category_id = :category_id';

       //prepare statement 
       $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

       //clean data 
       $this->title = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->title));
       $this->body = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->body));
       $this->author = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->author));
       $this->category_id = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->category_id));
        //bind data 
        $stmt->bindParam(':title', $this->title);
        $stmt->bindParam(':body', $this->body);
        $stmt->bindParam(':author', $this->author);
        $stmt->bindParam(':category_id', $this->category_id);

        // Execute query 
        if($stmt->execute())
            {
                return true;
            }
        // Print error if something goes wrong 
        printf("Error: %s.\n", $stmt->error);
        return false;
}
```

**API: Create.php**

```
<?php

// Headers 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
//add more for creating  a post 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-headers,
Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Methods,
Authorization, X-Requested-with');

include_once '../../config/Database.php';
include_once '../../models/Post.php';

//Instantiate DB & connect
$database = new Database();
$db =$database->connect();

//initiate blog post object
$post = new Post($db);

//we need to get the data was posted 
//Get the raw posted data 
$data =json_decode(trim(file_get_contents("php://input")));
$post->title = $data->title;
$post->body = $data->body;
$post->author = $data->author;
$post->category_id = $data->category_id;

//create post 
if($post->create()) {
    echo json_encode(
      array('message' => 'Post Created')
    );
} else{
    echo json_encode(
        array('message' => 'Post not created!')
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually common when not passing the body params properly. I will suggest if you can use fetch instead of axios and also introduce JSON.stringify(body). However, I have rewritten the code for you.

```
    onCreate = event => {
    event.preventDefault();  
    let cat_id = (this.state.cat + 1);
    const someValue = {
       'author' :this.state.author,
      'title': this.state.title,
      'body' : this.state.body,
      'category_id':String(cat_id)
    };

    fetch(`http://localhost/rest_api_myblog/api/post/create.php`,
    { method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept':'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(someValue)})
    .then(res => {console.log(res)
    })
   .catch(e => console.log(e));
   this.setState({
     author: " ", 
     title: "",

   });
  }
```

Comment: Can I try the new changes with Axios and see if it is going to work?

Comment: well it is your choice. Fetch API gives high level of specificity which helps to trace error easily